# Pandas replace with value from another row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, replace, series

I have a table:

| Object | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| reference | 10 | 14 | 7 | 29 |
| Obj1 | 0 | 9 | 1 | 30 |
| Obj2 | 1 | 16 | 0 | 17 |
| Obj3 | 9 | 21 | 3 | 0 |
| Obj4 | 11 | 0 | 4 | 22 |

I want to transform it by condition: if any cell (except the cells of the 1st row) is =0, then it must be replaced with an incremented (X+1) value from the 1st row of this column.

The resulting table is:

| Object | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| reference | 10 | 14 | 7 | 29 |
| Obj1 | 11 | 9 | 1 | 30 |
| Obj2 | 1 | 16 | 8 | 17 |
| Obj3 | 9 | 21 | 3 | 30 |
| Obj4 | 11 | 15 | 4 | 22 |

I've tried this variant:

```
df = np.where(df[df == 0] == 0, df.iloc[0] + 1, df)
```

but the result is `ndarray`, not DataFrame and the performance is not well enough.

Is there a way to do this using only pandas' utils?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
out = df.mask(df == 0, df.iloc[0] + 1, axis=1)
print (out)
           Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
Object                           
reference    10    14     7    29
Obj1         11     9     1    30
Obj2          1    16     8    17
Obj3          9    21     3    30
Obj4         11    15     4    22
```

Comment: Adding to this you may also use `df.where(df != 0, df.iloc[0] + 1, axis=1)`. It's giving the same result. But, `df.mask()` seems more intuitive here as it updates the value if the condition is true (df == 0) whereas `df.where()` updates the value if the condition is false (if df != 0 is False then update).